# ILIKE Compare Strings

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm looking to match a list against user input data. The list is clean, the user input is messy. I want to be able to return a 1 for the following query;

`SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '') ILIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%',REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s Pizza Dublin', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '')),'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END compare`

In my setup 'Domino''s' and 'Domino''s Pizza Dublin' is part of a dynamic list and are not fixed.

Any suggestions on how to get the above to return 1 instead of 0 would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is returning 1 on my end.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '') AS string1_clean,
    REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s Pizza Dublin', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '') AS string2_clean,
    '%' || REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s Pizza Dublin', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '') || '%' AS string2_clean_wildcard,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s Pizza Dublin', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '') ILIKE '%' ||REGEXP_REPLACE('Domino''s', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '')  || '%' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS compare;
```